# Best Note Application Integrated With Exchange For IPad 2

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, windows, exchange-activesync

I am looking for a note taking application that needs to be integrated with MS Exchange, because i am using an iPad, a notebook running Windows 7 and MacBook Pro.

- I want to be able to take notes, create tasks and access them from all devices.

Is there any program that meets these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen posts that say if you are synced to Exchange, the built-in Reminders app will sync your tasks; there is a slider for it in the Exchange setup. As far as a third-party app, try IMExchange2, it appears to sync tasks and notes.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be integrated with Exchange? Would a third-party service work?

Like SimpleNote. It has a web interface - so you can access it from any computer-, **[an universal app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/simplenote/id289429962?mt=8)** (iPhone + iPad) and many other [**third party app**](http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/) for Windows and OS X.